# parsing 3 lists into list of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, ordereddictionary

I'm parsing a csv line by line.  There are 3 columns in a row that need to be each split into lists and then combined into dictionaries in a list.  The data inside each column is separated by two pipes: `||`

**incoming data:**

buttons, clicked, id
choice 1 || choice 2 || choice 3,   TRUE || FALSE || FALSE, choice 1 id|| choice 2 id || choice 3 id

[image]

- the data was already imported via csv DiskReader and each row in the script is ordered dictionary and looks like:

```
('buttons','choice 1 || choice 2 || choice 3'),
('clicked', 'TRUE || FALSE || FALSE'),
('id','choice 1 id|| choice 2 id || choice 3 id'),
```

*EDITED TO ADD*:
input has a lot more columns that should not be included.  only these 3 columns are included for this step.

i.e. sample output of a row that is being processed

```
print(data[0])

OrderedDict([
('pathId', 'test_id'),
('stepId', ''),
('nodeId', 'ROOT'),
('responseId', 'test_response'),
('responseUuid', ''),
('type', ''),
('language', 'en-US'),
('buttons','choice 1 || choice 2 || choice 3'),
('clicked', 'TRUE || FALSE || FALSE'),
('id','choice 1 id|| choice 2 id || choice 3 id'),
('state', 'resolved'),
('flags', 'accepted')])
```

the actual number of columns is dynamic and unpredictable.  But in rows that contain values for  `buttons`, `clicked` and `id` will need this processing.
*END EDIT*

**Expected output** for this row needs to be:

```
buttonChoices =
[
    {
        "button": "choice 1",
        "clicked": true,
        "id": "choice 1 id"
    },
    {
        "button": "choice 2",
        "clicked": false,
        "id": "choice 2 id"
    },
    {
        "button": "choice 3",
        "clicked": false,
        "id": "choice 3 id"
    }
]
```

- i don't know in advance how many values will be in the list, but it will be same in these 3 columns

For now I have:

```
for row in data:
    buttonChoices = []
    buttonText = row['button'].split('||')
    buttonClicked = row['clicked'].split('||')
    buttonId = row['id'].split('||')
```

but stuck for next step

Comment: Why does your CSV look like this? Why isn't there a separate row of data for each button-click event?

Comment: it is what it is...  all related records come in one row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use zip to combine the values 3 by 3 and to associate them to a key:

```
data = dict([ ('buttons','choice 1 || choice 2 || choice 3'),
              ('clicked', 'TRUE || FALSE || FALSE'),
              ('id','choice 1 id|| choice 2 id || choice 3 id')])

buttonChoices = [ dict(zip(data,map(str.strip,values)))
                  for values in zip(*(v.split("||") for v in data.values())) ]

print(buttonChoices)
[{'buttons': 'choice 1', 'clicked': 'TRUE', 'id': 'choice 1 id'},
 {'buttons': 'choice 2', 'clicked': 'FALSE', 'id': 'choice 2 id'},
 {'buttons': 'choice 3', 'clicked': 'FALSE', 'id': 'choice 3 id'}]
```

*note: I added a map(str.strip,...) in there to clean up the messy string separations but you don't need it if your actual data is properly formatted*

To generalize this a bit, you can define input keys and output keys to filter and rename as needed:

```
inKeys  = ('buttons','clicked','id')
outKeys = ('button','clicked','id')
buttonChoices = [ dict(zip(outKeys,map(str.strip,values)))
                  for values in zip(*(data[k].split("||") for k in inKeys)) ]

print(buttonChoices)
[{'button': 'choice 1', 'clicked': 'TRUE', 'id': 'choice 1 id'},
 {'button': 'choice 2', 'clicked': 'FALSE', 'id': 'choice 2 id'},
 {'button': 'choice 3', 'clicked': 'FALSE', 'id': 'choice 3 id'}]
```

Comment: I think this works if there are no other dictionary values in 'data', but there are lots more columns in original csv that don't need to be added to this section.  (they get separate processing) Is there a way to limit by keys what is in `data`?  something like pandas `data['buttons', 'clicked', 'id]`?

Comment: It should be possible but I would need to see an example of the source data and expected exclusion (in your question, not in a comment) to properly answer that.

Comment: I added the edit to the question

Comment: I see, the 'generalized' version I added to my answer should cover that.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the problem correctly, then this should work.

```
    button_choices = []
    for row in data:
        button_texts = row['button'].split('||')
        button_clickeds = row['clicked'].split('||')
        button_ids = row['id'].split('||')
        for button_text, button_clicked, button_id in zip(button_texts, button_clickeds, button_ids):
            button_choices.append({
                'button': button_text,
                'clicked': button_clicked,
                'id': button_id
            })
```